# Is it possible to have a model object with list of children of a specific length?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I want my model to have a list of children with specific length, Is it possible to set the length within the model, "DDD style"?

An example is a deck of cards having 52 cards.

```
public class Deck
{
    List<Card> Cards { get; set; } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677278/limit-the-size-of-listof-t-vb-net

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd need to implement this custom limitation within the `Deck` class and not expose the `List<Card>` as a public member:

```
public class Deck
{
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Deck()
    {
        cards = new List<Card>();
    }

    public void Add(Card card)
    {
        if (cards.Count == 52)
        { 
            throw new TooManyCardsException();
        }
        cards.Add(card);
    }

    public void Remove();
    {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: assuming there is a reason to use List<T> here you may be well served by having Add and Remove return bool values to denote success of the operation.  You can avoid throwing an exception which can be costly at runtime.  I once wrote a recursive algorithm that relied on throwing exceptions... needless to say I didn't understand the performance penalty.. and it was super slow lol.

Comment: Good point; it all depends on the design. One of the philosophies is you throw an exception and then handle it in, say the UI layer, and say "Oops, can't add another card!"; Another way would be to return a bool as you say; then other layers down the line have to know what to do with the success/return value. The exception method may be overkill here, agreed; it's more appropriate in large multi-layer/multi-level systems where an exception can get thrown from another DLL for example and needs to be handled in a higher layer closer to where a user may be, or a junior programmer as it were.

Comment: Yeah excellent point. As you stated, it's really about who's going to handle it, and who needs to know it was handled.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the deck will always have 52 cards, then why not make in an array with fixed size? Ultimately if the deck is open for modification by collaborators, then you may want to do what was mentioned in the other answer and provide some safeguards in your class to protect the `Deck` object.  If the `Deck` model's card array/list is read-only to the outside, then I stand by the array idea.

Comment: thanks for your answer. like so? public Card[] Cards = new Card[52];

Comment: That's why I upvoted your answer. The array idea does the job. My version is heavier and I went with the assumption the OP had a reason for using a List<T>.

Comment: Thanks. I thought to use List because by my understanding it's more "conventional", and also wanted to practice having the business rule (which is 'deck.count = 52') in the model